# Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configur

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When I try to access the database on the server online it gives me this error
I tried to log in from another browser but it gives the same error
I cant to access to dahboard of website
How can I solve this problem please
What are the causes of this problem?

[image]

Comment: “No space left on device” – sounds like it doesn’t have any more HDD space available to write any session files. Contact your server admin.

Comment: Thank you its correct there is no space , i contacted my server admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is there is no space in my server we solved this problem by clean the server old backup
and in database phpmyadmin it was in the debugger mode and every query in my project was saving in database we cleaned it by delete the querys